# use to parameter for querystring with Eval

Tags: c#, asp.net, hyperlink, query-string

I have a datalist and there is a hyperlink in that, in navigateurl I want use of QueryString.
This is the DataSource of an asp:DataList:

```
 public void GalleryListDS()
    {

        int UserID = Convert.ToInt32(ViewState["UserID"]);

        var n = from gi in DataContext.Context.GalleryImages
                join g in DataContext.Context.Galleries
                on gi.GalleryID equals g.GalleryID
                where g.UserID == UserID && gi.IsAlbumImage == true
                select new
                {
                    UserID=g.UserID,
                    GalleryID = g.GalleryID,
                    ImageDescription = gi.ImageDescription,
                    GalleryName=g.GalleryName,
                    ImageFileName = gi.ImageFileName
                };

        dlGalleryList.DataSource = n;
        dlGalleryList.DataBind();

    }
```

And this is my DataList:

```
 <asp:DataList ID="dlGalleryList" runat="server" RepeatColumns="3">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <div class="gallery">
              <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" runat="server" NavigateUrl='<%# Eval("GalleryID","~/Profile/UserImages.aspx?ImgID={0}") %>'>
                '<%# Eval("GalleryName")%>'
            </asp:HyperLink>
            </div>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:DataList>
```

I want my QueryString to have a Parameter like so:

```
  <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" runat="server" NavigateUrl='<%# Eval("GalleryID","UserID","~/Profile/UserImages.aspx?ImgID={0}&ProfileID={1}") %>'>
```

but this does not achieve the desired result.

Answer (score 1):

use `<%=` instead of `<%#`

like-

```
NavigateUrl='<%= Eval("GalleryID","UserID","~/Profile/UserImages.aspx?ImgID={0}&ProfileID={1}") %>'
```

Comment: when i click on this hyperlink the new page show me HTTP Error 400 - Bad Request. and the URL bar show "http://localhost:55659/Profile/%3C%=%20Eval%28%22GalleryID%22,%22UserID%22,%22~/Profile/UserImages.aspx?ImgID={0}&ProfileID={1}%22%29%20%%3E"

Answer (score 1):

`Eval` has the syntax:

```
public static string Eval(
    Object container,
    string expression,
    string format
)
```

[ You can skip the Container by the way, ]
Use :

```
NavigateUrl='<%#CombinePath(
DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"GalleryID","~/Profile/UserImages.aspx?ImgID={0}").ToString(),
DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"UserID","&ProfileID={0}").ToString()) %>'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do in this way

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" runat="server" NavigateUrl='<%= "~/Profile/UserImages.aspx?ImgID=" + Eval("GalleryID") + "&ProfileID=" + Eval("UserID") %>'>
```

Comment: when i click on this hyperlink the new page show me HTTP Error 400 - Bad Request.